# Jquery listview content set but does not show in UI?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a page with a JQM listview on it.

Its has default values to it similar to a nested structure.

When i select an item on the listview i goes to the other page where further options are listed.

On selecting the option on the data is passed to the previous page. The data is being set into the listview container but the listview still shows the older value.

This is what i am trying to do.

```
var bookedForVal = selectedValuePage.bookedFor;
console.log("Selected Value Text",$selectObj.find(".selected_value").html());
$selectObj.find(".selected_value").text(bookedForVal);
console.log("Selected Value Text",$selectObj.find(".selected_value").html());
$("ul:jqmData[role='listview']").listview("refresh");
```

This piece of code is called on the **pagebeforeshow** event.

Comment: Do you have more then one element with a class .selected_value?

Comment: Yes but they belong to different elements

Comment: It doesn't matter, they are all inside same DOM, basically your code has accessed first element with a class .selected_value found in the DOM and changed its content. You need to be careful with this when working with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Yes i do agree to your point. Here the $selectObj points to the element for which the selection has been made. And my point being.. The values are set as i can see them on the console but its not reflected on the UI.

Comment: Are you clearing the list view before appending new data (as per listed item in the prev page) The "page where further options are listed."

Comment: I guess it's a duplicate selector problem. you should be specific in your selection `$('#Page_ID ul li.selector')`

Comment: @OMAR: As specified I am already calling this functionality in pageforeshow event which only fires when the page with respected id is returned.

Comment: @Sheetal I just need to change the text in the view which could be visible by the user why do i need to empty the listview ?

Comment: oh okay sorry, then ensure that the text element is cleared before displaying different data, sometimes the old data is shown.

Comment: @Sheetal: Its still not working